# Can an aborted HTTP fetch from a web browser (abortController abort()) be recognized in a Go backend app (using the Context package)?

Tags: javascript, go, axios, abortcontroller

I'm having problems troubleshooting why a cancelled request in the frontend isn't reaching a backend API. In other words, sending a GET/POST request using axios works just fine. But once .abort() kicks in, the network console shows request cancelled, which is also fine, *but the backend does not recognized this cancellation*.

The frontend code is identical to the following:
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4338#issuecomment-1002364900

Unfortunately, according to the backend api logs, the requests go through as normal. No canceled request or error appears in the backend logs.

On a related note, when a similar request is made from other clients, like using `curl` in a terminal, or from a  desktop app: `Postman`, for example, the backend recognizes the cancellation or abrupt stoppage (like hitting Ctrl+C on a `curl`), and the logs show: `error: timeout: context canceled`

Is it just not possible for javascript's abort() (via browser) to be picked up in the backend (Go app using `ctx.Done()`? Is there something special a CURL request is signaling that an aborted request from the browser isn't?

Comment: why can't you communicate from the browser to your server? Why can't your JavaScript do that?

Comment: Not sure what your question refers to. A regular axios GET or POST request works, but when I cancel it via AbortController, the request still works. The problem is, it's not supposed to work, this uses up backend resources unnecessarily.

Comment: What do you expect to be sent to the server to indicate the cancelled request? I don’t believe `AbortController` signals anything to the server to indicate as such

Comment: If the request connection was not closed before being read entirely, there is no other information to be obtained, the request is already sent.

Comment: It's possible using JavaScript in a server.

Comment: @esqew _"I don’t believe AbortController signals anything to the server to indicate as such"_ It does. You can get that signal in `cancel()` method of a `ReadableStream`, including the cancel `reason`. And/or in `abort()` method of a `WritableStream` a posted `ReadableStream` is piped to in the server.

Comment: @NoonTime I don't know about Go, the requirement is definitely possible using a `deno` server and WHATWG Streams. I've used `AbortController` from the client a few different ways, in the server something like `async cancel(reason) {console.log('cancelled', reason);console.log(command, process);process.kill('SIGKILL');}` in a `ReadableStream` served back to the client, that remains persistent, potentially indefinitely, until one side of the half-duplex stream cancels, or aborts the connection.

Comment: That's the thing about 3rd party modules... If you just use native browser fetch , you're less likely to encounter janky behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I just verified (with local express node server proxying requests to backend API, and a sample html file that calls abort() when user presses the cancel button) that yes, it is possible. I also tried this with axios `tokensource = axios.CancelToken.source(); tokensource.cancel()` which also works. Then when I use AbortController inside the proxy.js,

```
const abortController = new AbortController();
const { signal } = abortController;
```

include the signal in the fetch, and call abort inside the app.post block (where app = express())

```
  req.on('aborted', () => {
    abortController.abort();
  });
```

the backend Go app picks it up and returns an error.

So the issue was the existing nginx proxy/middleware, which lacks something like the above to propagate this signal.